# Remove consecutive duplicates from dataframe

Tags: r, range

I have a data frame that I want to remove duplicates that are consecutive (in base).  I know `rle` may be helpful here but can't think of how to use it.  The example output will help to illuminate what I'm asking for.

**Generate sample data:**

```
set.seed(12)
samps <- sample(1:5, 20, T)
dat <- data.frame(v1=LETTERS[samps], v2=month.abb[samps])
dat[10, 2] <- "Mar"
```

**Sample data:**

```
   v1  v2
1   A Jan
2   E May
3   E May
4   B Feb
5   A Jan
6   A Jan
7   A Jan
8   D Apr
9   A Jan
10  A Mar
11  B Feb
12  E May
13  B Feb
14  B Feb
15  B Feb
16  C Mar
17  C Mar
18  C Mar
19  D Apr
20  A Jan
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
   v1  v2
1   A Jan
3   E May
4   B Feb
7   A Jan
8   D Apr
10  A Mar
11  B Feb
12  E May
15  B Feb
18  C Mar
19  D Apr
20  A Jan
```

Comment: It appears that one could filter on a single column for your example, but is that the intent?

Comment: no this is not the intent, just for convenience I made the two columns identical.  I edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a way, not with `rle`, but a way none-the-less:

```
dat[with(dat, c(TRUE, diff(as.numeric(interaction(v1, v2))) != 0)), ]
```

This assumes you're using `factor` columns, as your sample data implies.

Answer (score 4):

Here a fast solution using filter

```
dat[(filter(dat,c(-1,1))!= 0)[,1],]
     v1   v2
1     A  Jan
3     E  May
4     B  Feb
7     A  Jan
8     D  Apr
10    A  Mar
11    B  Feb
12    E  May
15    B  Feb
18    C  Mar
19    D  Apr
NA <NA> <NA>
```

You need to add the last value of the original data to the result.

Comment: Thoughtful response thank you for your work on the problem.  I rarely think about filter so seeing a usage was informative.

Answer (score 3):

Using `rle` I came up with this

```
ind <- cumsum(rle(as.character(dat$v1))$length)
dat[ind, ]
```

`ind` indicates either the first or the last of consecutive entries.

EDIT:

A simple solution to Matthews comment would be

```
dat[15, 2] <- "May"
dat[cumsum(rle(paste0(dat$v1, dat$v2))$length), ]
```

Comment: This works on OP's sample data, but would fail if there were, say, two consecutive rows, 'E Feb' and 'E May'.

Comment: you're right! I assumed the two columns would always have same values.

Comment: Thank you for your work.  @Matthew's is a little more generalizable.