# count shared occurrences and remove duplicates

Tags: r, plyr

I have this  `data.frame` :

```
df <- read.table(text= "   section to from    time
                             a     1  5        9       
                             a     2  5        9        
                             a     1  5        10       
                             a     2  6        10       
                             a     2  7        11       
                             a     2  7        12       
                             a     3  7        12       
                             a     4  7        12
                             a     4  6        13  ", header = TRUE)
```

Each row identifies the simultaneoues occurence of an id in `to` and `from` at a timepoint `time`. Basically  a time explicit network of ids in `to` and `from`.

I want to know which `to` ids shared a `from` id within a particular time range which is `2`. In otherwards i want to know if ids 1 and 2 in `to` both went to coffee shop `5` within two days of each other., i.e.

id `1` and `2` in `to` shared id `5` in `from` at `time` 9 and 10 respectively and so would have  `1` shared events within the time window 2. If they also shared a `from` id at time point 13 e.g.

```
                             a     1  5        9       
                             a     2  5        9        
                             a     1  7        13       
                             a     2  7        13
```

then `1` and `2` would get a `2`

So the final output I would like for the `df` would be:

```
                           section to.a to.b    noShared
                             a     1    2        1       
                             a     2    3        1        
                             a     2    4        1       
                             a     3    4        1
```

I can get some of the way there with:

```
library(plyr)                            
library(tnet)


a <- ddply(df, .(section,to,time), function(x)  
          data.frame(from = unique(x$from)) )

b <- ddply(a, .(section,time), function(x) {

            b <- as.tnet(x[, c("to","from")], type="binary two-mode tnet")
            b <- projecting_tm(b, method="sum")
            return(b)

       })
```

This gets me which ids in `to` shared ids in `from` within each `time` point.

However there are two main problems with `b`.

**Firstly** within each time point the pairs of `ids` appear twice in both directions i.e.

```
 1  2  5  9 # id 1 and 2 went to coffee shop 5  at time 9
 2  1  5  9 # id 2  and 1 went to coffee shop 5 at time 9

 I only want each sombination to appear once: 

  1  2  5  # id 1 and 2 went to coffee shop 5  at time 9</strike>
```

<strike>**Secondly** I need to bin the results within the time window so that my final result doesnt hav time just number of shared events i.e.</strike>

---

**EDIT**

The time issue has more issues than expected. The first problem is enough for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the generation of b (first part of the question)

I change the code `projecteing_tm` wihch is transformation of a network.

```
b <- ddply(a, .(section,time), function(x) {
  ## first I create the origin network
  net2 <- x[, c("to","from")]
  colnames(net2) <- c('i','p')
  net2 <- net2[order(net2[, "i"], net2[, "p"]), ]
  np <- table(net2[, "p"])
  net2 <- merge(net2, cbind(p = as.numeric(rownames(np)),np = np))
  ## trasnformed network
  net1 <- merge(net2, cbind(j = net2[, "i"], p = net2[, "p"]))
  net1 <- net1[net1[, "i"] != net1[, "j"], c("i", "j","np")]
  net1 <- net1[order(net1[, "i"], net1[, "j"]), ]
  index <- !duplicated(net1[, c("i", "j")])
  net1 <- cbind(net1[index, c("i", "j")])
  net1
})
```

So here you get your b without any warning

```
> b
  section time i j
1       a    9 1 2
2       a    9 2 1
3       a   12 2 3
4       a   12 2 4
5       a   12 3 2
6       a   12 3 4
7       a   12 4 2
8       a   12 4 3
```

For the second part of the question , do you want to remove duplicated from b?

```
b[!duplicated(t(apply(b[3:4], 1, sort))), ]
  section time i j
1       a    9 1 2
3       a   12 2 3
4       a   12 2 4
6       a   12 3 4
```

For this part Here I use an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078507/remove-duplicated-2-columns-permutations).

Comment: nice use of `t` thats a great way to remove within time point duplicates.

Comment: @user1317221_G I can't get how to transform this result to binned form? can you do it on this example?

Comment: its actually much more annoying than i originally suggested. Happy with this one question and one answer.

Comment: @user1317221_G do you will use my method to generate b juste you are ahappy with duplicated issue?